# How to send separate keystrokes to separate programs?

Tags: windows

Say I have 2 programs open: Program A and program B.
I want to tell program A that I am holding down *CAPSLOCK*, but I want to still be able to navigate and use program B during this.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to send separate keystrokes to separate programs?

You can download and use the free [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) program and its [WinActivate()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm) and [Send()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm) functions in particular to select a specific window based on its title (metadata). You can even [Send()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm) emulated keystrokes or even navigate a specific window mouse coordination and [MouseClick()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm) too.

### Sample Script

```
WinWait("ProgramA", "", 10)
WinActivate("ProgramA")
MouseClick("left", 504, 549, 1, 30)
Send("AbCdEfG")
Sleep(100)
WinWait("ProgramB", "", 10)
WinActivate("ProgramB")
MouseClick("left", 504, 549, 1, 30)
Send("HiJkLmNo")
```

### Further Resources

- [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)
- [WinWait()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm)
- [WinActivate()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm)
- [Send()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm)
- [MouseClick()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm)